# Laravel Many to Many - 3 models

Tags: laravel

Some help with many to many relationships in Laravel:

Using the example for roles and users - basically:

- a table for all the roles
- a table for the users
- and table with    user_id and role_id.

I want to add to the third table, eg Year. basically the pivot table will have user_id, role_id and year_id.

I want to be able to make a query to pull for example all users assigned a specific role in a specific year. Eg All users with role_id = 2, and year_id = 1.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: why u want to use third table for year id? why can't u put year_id in users table or table with user_id and role_id? what are the relationships?

Comment: basically, you can have one user assigned different roles in different years, meaning in year 1, a user can have role a, and in year 2, he has role b. So i want to see all users assigned role a in year 1 for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before answering, I would like to suggest you not to put year on database like this.
All your tables should have `created_at` and `updated_at` which should be enough for that.

To filter users like you want. You could do this:

```php
// This queries all users that were assigned to 'admin' role within 2013.
User::join('role_users', 'role_users.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->join('roles', 'roles.id', '=', 'role_users.role_id')
    ->where('roles.name', '=', 'admin')
    ->where(DB::raw('YEAR(role_users.created_at)', '=', '2013')
    ->get();
```

This example may not be the precise query you are looking for, but should be enough for you to come up with it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve a three way relation with Eloquent is to create a model for the table representing this relation. Pivot tables is meant to be used for two way relations.

You could have then a table called `roles_users_year` which could have data related to this 3 way relation like a timestamp or whatever...

Answer (score 0):

A very late answer to a very old question, but Laravel has supported additional intermediate (pivot) table columns of at least Laravel 5.1 judging from the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many), which hasn't changed at least through Laravel 6.x.

You can describe these extra columns when defining your many-to-many relationship:

```php
return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class)->withPivot('column1', 'column2');
```

or in your case, the below would also do the job:

```php
return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class)->withTimestamps();
```

which you can then access via the `pivot` attribute on your model:

```php
$user = User::find(1);

foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
    echo $role->pivot->created_at;
}
```

Note that the pivot attribute is on the distant relationship *model* (a single `Role`) and not on the relationship itself.

To get all the `Role`s assigned to `User`s in any given year, you might create a special relationship:

```php
// User.php

public function rolesInYear($year) {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class)
        ->wherePivot('created_at', '>=', Carbon::create($year))
        ->wherePivot('created_at', '<', Carbon::create($year + 1));
}
```